# jqgrid search event

Tags: events, search, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid and i need to update a graph (jquery flot) based on the content of the grid.

My question is, is there an event that i can catch each time a search is preformed??

I've been reading the documentation on jqgrid but so far i just can update the graph when the grid is created not when a search is done.

Any help you can give me would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can a little depend on which form of searching you use. The event [onInitializeSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#options) can be a good choice. If it helps you not, you should append your question with more information which searching way you use ([Toolbar Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching), [Single field searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching), [Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching) or [Custom Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_searching)) and at what moment (before, after ...) you need to receive an event.

Moreover probably you need catch not really the search event, but the [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) event for example. On every reloading of the grid and on every searching the event handler are called at the end of processing.

Comment: Hi! I have already tried the loadComplete event and it works if i refresh the entire page on the browser. But the strange thing is that it does not when i preform a search. The event simply its not catch. That loadComplete would be perfect if it was fired on search.

Comment: @fmarinheiro: The `loadComplete` must be fired on searching. If it is not work in your case you should append your question wither a code example which can be used to reproduce your problem. Either you find a bug in jqGrid or you made a small error in the usage of jqGrid. In both cases the code example will be needed.

Comment: Ok, the load complete works was my error. When setting grid options e was making: 

......
gridview: true,
loadComplete: functionIWantToCall(param),
......

Now i make this way:

......
gridview: true,
loadComplete: function(){ functionIWantToCall(param); },
......

Don't know why it doesn't work the first way but now it's working fine.

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @fmarinheiro: The problem with the `loadComplete` syntax is very easy to explain. If you use syntax `loadComplete: functionIWantToCall(param)`, it means that the function `functionIWantToCall(param)` will be executed **at the grid initialization time** and you define `loadComplete` as a property not as a function which could be called at the time when needed.

Comment: @Oleg: Ok, thank you now i understand the problem. I'm not very experienced with jqgrid nor JavaScript either but we are always learning.
Keep it up!

Sorry for the English :)

Comment: @fmarinheiro: You welcome! It seems to me that my English in not better as yours. About one year ago (probably about 15 Months) I also started with JavaScript and a Months later with jQuery and jqGrid. Now I know much more about jqGrid. Probably in a year you will know it better as me. Good luck!